# How to recalculate a field relating to another table (Yii2 MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, yii2

I have MySQL database and table 'User' with field 'rating' in it. Also, I have 'Rating' table with 'user_id' and 'value' columns. I need to automatically get the medium value of the 'value' column in 'Rating' table and put it to the user's 'rating' field everytime someone votes for this user or just if we add/change rows in database. I tried "afterSave()" function in my Rating model in Yii2, but it only works if rating value is saved from form in view (by voting with radiobuttons). If I change values in database, it doesn't recalculate the 'rating' field, of course.I guess I need to do something with SQL, not with the framework, am I right? How is this usually done?

Comment: That 's right. You must use mysql procedure or create a crontab

Comment: Will any user change rating directly in Database? 
If yes then you need to do logic at database side.
If no then it can be managed by Yii2.

Comment: I mean, users will vote only from form. The idea is that administrator (who has an access to a database) can change it in database and it will be automatically renewed in the 'rating' field.

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can use [mysql triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html), that are sort of event handlers, that activates when a particular event occurs for the table e.g *INSERT*, *UPDATE* or *DELETE* row. Here is [an article](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/) about using triggers.